# Javascript split screen view

Tags: javascript, splitview

Is it possible to make split screen view with javascript in order to view two parts of a website at the same time? I am looking forward to make something like Microsoft Word has when you need to edit or view two separate parts of one document.

Comment: You could use *iframe* tag

Answer (score 3):

I have found [split.js](https://github.com/nathancahill/Split.js)

Split.js is a lightweight, unopinionated utility for creating adjustable split views or panes

**HTML:**

```
<div id="a" class="split split-horizontal">
  <div id="c" class="split content"></div>
  <div id="d" class="split content"></div>
</div>
<div id="b" class="split split-horizontal">
  <div id="e" class="split content"></div>
  <div id="f" class="split content"></div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
Split(['#a', '#b'], {
  gutterSize: 8,
  cursor: 'col-resize'
})
Split(['#c', '#d'], {
  direction: 'vertical',
  sizes: [25, 75],
  gutterSize: 8,
  cursor: 'row-resize'
})
Split(['#e', '#f'], {
  direction: 'vertical',
  sizes: [25, 75],
  gutterSize: 8,
  cursor: 'row-resize'
})
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/h3cvm2ws/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use frameset tag.

```
<frameset cols="250px,*">
  <frame src="/your/menu/bar">
  <frameset rows="50%,*">
    <frame src="/your/splitted/content">
    <frame src="/your/splitted/content">
  </frameset>
</frameset>
```

Each frame can be manipulated by JS

Comment: The `<frameset>` tag is deprecated - I wouldn't use it for any new development...

Answer (score 0):

I do not know for something that is ready directly for this, but i have an idea that may help you.

Use canvas and make screenshot of the document.
Put the canvas on the one part of the screen and the actuall document on anoter. 
The moment the user clicks on the canvas, switch the places of the real item and the canvas.
You can get away with this kind of cheat, sunce the focus can be only on one place at a time.
Of course you need to reftresh the canvs oftern and you will need to play with the scroll position, but it can turn out nice.

Comment: Cannot do that since I have table generated from database. So the contents for every user are unique. I was hoping to make the site split in half so the user can view two sections of the page at the same time and make data entry easier.

Comment: The screenshot of the page dose not have to be a static one. I have used this librarry long time ago, that was doing exactly this https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

you can just replace the canvas image every now and then, or every time a change happens on the page