# Button in HTML to split the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a button in HTML that when it is pressed the screen it's split. Press 1 time the screen splits in 2, press again and it splits in 3,... and I don't how to make it functional. Can you help me? Just need the JavaScript to make it work. The button id is "split screen button".

Comment: when you mentioned split screen , did you mean a div ?

Comment: Can you show us what you have attempted so far with examples of your code along with some information related to any research you have completed in regards to your issue?  This would make it bit easier to help you solve your problem.

Comment: That's not a valid element ID value.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at [Split.js](https://split.js.org/), which is a small library for achieving split screen functionality. The [source](https://github.com/nathancahill/split) is also available on GitHub. Here is some [additional information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40357373/javascript-split-screen-view) about usage from a previous question on Stack Overflow.

If you try to do this using strict HMTL/CSS you will still need to access the DOM through a bit of Javascript to add new DIV elements.

```
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(div);
```

The above code should do the trick of actually creating the element. You will, of course, still need to define its parameters and style it. Depending on what you plan to do with the split panes, it may be simpler to use an existing library.